# How to load all images before showing the page in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to find a more modern solution that doesn't use jQuery as I am using React (Gatsbyjs specifically).

I have a website with multiple image carousels that contain high res images.

The issue is the each image carousel only show one image at a time, so only when the user navigates to the next image does the image get fetched, this results in a choppy loading appearance.

I have tried researching online with `onLoad` and `load` event listeners but none seem to have worked so far because they only load the image that is currently being shown by the carousel, instead of ***all of the images*** in the carousel.

If there is a way to first load all the images, then set the state to true, and only after the state is true, then the rest of the DOM appears onto the screen, that would be perfect.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Website in question: https://dev--yachtgamechanger.netlify.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Lonnie Best said, I ended up using `Promise.all()` to capture the loads of the images.

Just in case anyone else want to check it out:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-image-preload-ptosn

Comment: i tried many other ways.
But i also ended up using this solution ** https://codesandbox.io/s/react-image-preload-ptosn**

Comment: But I feel like it will error out if it failed to load one of the images. Failed to load one should not result in failure to load all.

Comment: According to the sandbox code, inside render the images are still being fetched from `IMAGES` static array. So, I am confused as to how are the images being loaded from cache and not directly by the url? Does this happen internally?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your lib is using lazy load approach. And it's really good when dueling with high res images.
You still can change the approach to load all the images before rendering the UI, by going into the carousel component, change the rendering behavior by checking whether all images be loaded or not before render.

Updated: Because you are using gatsby-image, so just use this property:
**loading: "eager"**. For EX:

```
<Img
        fixed={data.file.childImageSharp.fixed}
        alt="Gatsby Docs are awesome"
        loading="eager"
 />
```

[image]
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/

Comment: I am using lazy load (gatsby-image) for all the images apart from the carousel. I can't use lazy load for the carousel because of an issue between animation libraries. How do I preload all the carousel images before loading? So that the images are loaded from the cache.

Comment: which package are you using for the carousel rendering? Or you coded by yourself, please share the code that I can give more detail answer

Comment: Thanks! But the thing is, the carousel images are not using gatsby-image. Because it creates a bug with the animation library (react-spring). Is there a way to preload the carousel images?

Answer (score -1):

You can ensure that an image is pre-downloaded 100% well before it gets displayed to the screen.

Simply create an [Image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) element and set its `src` property to the URL where the image is located. Then use the image's `onload` event to detect when it is ready for instant display.

```js
// Image to Pre-Download:
var image = new Image();
console.time("Image Fully Downloaded in");
image.src = "https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/pia24870.jpeg";
image.onload = function()
{
    console.timeEnd("Image Fully Downloaded in");
    console.log("Image is ready for viewing.");
    clearInterval(interval);
    progress.parentNode.replaceChild(btn, progress);
    
}

// Fake Progress Indicator:
let progress = document.createElement("progress");
progress.value = 3;
progress.max = 100;
progress.textContent = "Fake Progress";
document.body.appendChild(progress);
let interval = setInterval(()=>
{
  if (progress.value === 99) 
  {
    progress.value = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    progress.value = progress.value + 1;
  }
},50)

// Button to Replace Progress Indicator:
let btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.textContent = "View Entire Image Instantly";
btn.addEventListener('click',function()
{
  this.parentNode.replaceChild(image, this);
});
```

```css
img { max-width: 100%; }
```

```html
<p>Only after the image is completely downloaded, will you see the button to view it:</p>
```

Based on this concept, you could pre-load/queue as many images as you like into [image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) objects, so that they are ready to be displayed instantly (well before the user decides to view the next image). Here's an example where I'm switching between preloaded images automatically (so fast that it looks like an animated gif -- but it is actually 27 separate images from 27 different URL locations): See [statue](http://www.lonniebest.com/Statue/) example and view source.

Comment: This seems close to what Im looking for. Where would you place this code inside react? Inside `useEffect`? So should I create an array of all the carousels images, then loop through them and queue them into image objects?

Comment: Well, you could create a [module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) that exports an array containing all the [image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) objects. Then, import that array into the module that needs to use those image objects. This doesn't depend on any framework. It should work in all of them.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, sorry.

Comment: A module is just a file that contains javascript code, but it allows you to export objects/arrays/etc you create within that file, so that other module files can import those things and use them. Specifically, you could create the array of [image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) objects (with set `src` properties) in a module and [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) that array so that you may import it into your main module and use the pre-downloaded images.

Comment: Okay, so I put all the image carousel images' urls inside an array, looped through them using `new Image()` and `image.src`. And it works! As soon as you load the page, all the images are downloading in the background. However, can I return a `Promise` for when the images have all downloaded, so that I can `setState`? Since I still want to create a loading screen until all the images have been fully downloaded.

Comment: Each image object has an onload event. Therefore, you could create an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) that returns a promise immediately and then only resolve that promise (with the image object) after that image object's onload event has fired. Instead of having an array of image objects, you could have an array of promises and use `await` or  [promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).